# Can I use 'drenching' to mean 'being drenched'?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, continuous-aspect

I understand 'drench' means to soak or get wet. Can I say 'I'm drenching in the rain' to mean that I'm standing in the rain and getting soaked by it? 
I mostly see 'drenching' being used only as a gerund. That's what had me confused.

Comment: You want to use it just as you've used *soaked*:  I'm standing in the rain and *getting drenched* by it.  Notice in that sentence that the rain is what is doing the drenching.  Therefore you cannot say that *you* are drenching- it is the rain that is drenching you.

Comment: Here's a comparable situation: You're standing in the rain, wondering about gerunds and getting confused. As you know, _confuse_ means to baffle or befuddle. QUESTION: Can you say "I'm confusing in the rain" and have it mean the same thing as "I'm getting confused in the rain?" ANSWER: No.

Comment: My confusion is the fact that you can say 'I'm totally drenched in the rain' (I guess), but not 'I'm drenching in the rain'.
I think an answer to whether 'drench' means 'to get wet' or 'to make something wet' would answer this :)

Comment: You can say that you are totally drenched **from** the rain because you are the object of the drenching.  The result of a drenching is to be drenched- it's still the rain acting on you.

Comment: @Joe “I’m drenching here!” is common? I've never heard it in my life, and Google gives me only one hit for the phrase apart from this page (and hardly any intransitive uses at all for just “I'm drenching”).

Comment: Janus - in short, I think you're right. I deleted that comment.  Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

To **drench** is a verb meaning to saturate something with water or make it extremely wet.

If you said "I am drenching" that means that you are the active agent causing something else to get wet. For example, it would be perfectly reasonable to say:

> I just **drenched** those anchovies in salad dressing.

Similarly, where the rain is the agent of the wetting and you are the object, you could say:

> The rain **drenched** me.

But it would be more idiomatic, as you note, to say:

> I got **drenched** [by the rain].

The rain is still the active agent, and is usually omitted.

Answer (score -5):

I think it is completely possible to use the word in the sentence as you did in a general way. But technically, I have no idea whether it is allowed or not.

A quick google gave me few references where people have used the word as you did.

Reference Links:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/drencing-in-rain/112775732150457
https://www.englishforums.com/English/WetSoakedDrenched/gwmjv/post.htm